# how to the access the file of system using java web applet?

Tags: java, security, tomcat, applet

I want to  access the file of the system using web applet. My Applet file work properly at the applet viewer, but when I used this applet on web it not working it generate exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.security.AccessControlException: 
 access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
```

Answer (score 1):

Applets that run in a browser run in a security-restricted sandbox environment and can't directly access the filesystem without being given permission to do so. See here for details on how to do this:

http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/HowCanAnAppletReadFilesOnTheLocalFileSystem

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify, the **permissions** you want to give to your applet, if nothing is specified and the applet is not signed, the applet will run in the **security sandbox**.

if the applet is **signed** and no permissions are specified, all permissions are requested.

[Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#PERMISSIONS)

> permissions Specifies the level of permissions that the applet needs
>   to run. The following values are valid:
>
> sandbox - The applet runs in the security sandbox. 
>   all-permissions -The applet requires access to resources on the user's system. 
>   default- If the applet is signed, all permissions are requested. Otherwise, the applet runs in the security sandbox.

```
 <APPLET> archive="my_applet.jar" code="MyApplet" width="300" height="300">
     <PARAM name="permissions" value="sandbox" />   
 </APPLET>
```

> If this parameter is omitted, default is assumed.

this [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/signing_applet_code_does_not) is also really interesting.

Comment: [off-topic] Is there any reason you approved [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3641727)? It clearly should have been rejected.

Comment: Well, you've approved 161 edits and rejected a grand total of four, which seems a bit suspicious...

Comment: I usually don't reject but rather skip suggested edits for which I'm not sure

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: no problem, it's good to see that someone is looking for good behavior on the site

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox applets cannot perform the following operations:
•They cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem, executable files, system clipboard, and printers.
•They cannot connect to or retrieve resources from any third party server (any server other than the server it originated from).
•They cannot load native libraries.
•They cannot change the SecurityManager.
•They cannot create a ClassLoader.
•They cannot read certain system properties. See System Properties for a list of forbidden system properties.

•They cannot read certain system properties. See System Properties for a list of forbidden system properties.

Privileged applets

Privileged applets do not have the security restrictions that are imposed on sandbox applets and can run outside the security sandbox.

If you want to read your own files you have to sign them.